# ¿Cómo puedo saber el color de una fila de un datagridview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Como ven en la imagen tengo un `DatagridView` el cual puede tener (x) cantidad filas ,las filas se pintaran de dos colores (rojo o verde).

Mi pregunta es ¿cómo obtengo el color de cada fila mediante código no de manera visual? Algo como:

```
if(datagrid.Rows[i].color=="verde")
{
    //console.writeline("la fila es verde")
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Necesitaríamos algo mas de información, por ejemplo...como estás pintando las filas?

Comment: me falto subir la imagen volveré a formular la pregunta

Comment: No hace falta que reformules. Pulsa en [edit] y añade o modifica todo lo que quieras :)

Answer (score 0):

Después de codear un rato esta es la solución:

```
if (dgvMoviFina.Rows[1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.LightGreen)
{
    MessageBox.Show("El color es verde");
}
```